# if controller affecting all other controllers jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Apache Jmeter. I have a script with different controllers inside a globalNav. I would want to make it so that if the condition in my first if controller is true, i send a certain cookie to all other requests in the other controllers. If the condition in the other if is true, i send another type of cookie to the other controllers

I know my if condition is correct because i tested it in its own controller but i can't seem to make it work globally. Please note that i'm new to Jmeter.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work this way, if you don't have any [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) under the If Controller the HTTP Cookie Manager will be silently ignored. Moreover according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) the cookie will be created only for the HTTP Request samplers which are under the particular If Controller.

I would rather go for [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the code like:

```
if (vars.get('somevar') == 'foo') { // change it to your condition like in the If Controller
    sampler.getCookieManager().add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie("my-cookie", "foo", "example.com", "/", false, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000))
} else {
    sampler.getCookieManager().add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie("my-cookie", "bar", "example.com", "/", false, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000))
}
```